# Most efficient way to double-export using Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom

I often want two copies of an image, one optimized for the web, and another optimized for printing.

The current method I have right now is during culling, rating the images. i have Lightroom filter by rating, and export in batch in two separate operations, first is web optimized, and the second is print optimized.

It gets a bit annoying because I don't necessarily want all the images exported for both ALL the time.

Is there any way to double export at one time? eg: it creates two jpgs at different export settings, with the click of 1 button/action?

Answer (score 1):

There are workarounds but no, not a native way.

You can export large images and then have another program create the smaller ones, or you can run two exports.

I just skip all that and use Image Processor Pro in Photoshop to create multiple sizes.

Answer (score 0):

No, Lightroom will not simultaneously create two different jpgs from one original image file. When you export images from Lightroom your export settings are applied to all files you've selected.

Comment: However, you CAN run two export operations at the same time, just start the second one while the first is executing.  If you have a multi-core CPU it will happily use all the cores and give you decent throughput.  I have had as many as 4 exports going simultaneously (Win7x64 Pro) while still having enough CPU left so the Windows UI is still quite responsive.

Comment: @JimGarrison, not sure if my comment must become a new question: when I export anything in LR 5.7 or 6.1 (64 bits, Win10, i5 4670K @3.4Ghz) all four cores are taken and driven up to 105% according to the Resource Monitor. RAM @ 50%, GPU idle, 2 SSDs under 10% usage.
It's becoming impossible to use LR, everything takes forever. I'm curious about your results. Can we share some export job times? It would help.
Ahn... I haven't posted much. How should I proceed with this?? Sorry!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need. I found a neat LR plugin called RC Export Manager, written by Rob Cole. You can write user presets for the type of exports you want to do, and configure Export Manager to run any number of them together. I've written 2 presets, one to export my photos simply as JPEGs, and another one to apply a watermark and export as JPEGs, to 2 different directories. When I ask lightroom to export a photo(s), Export Manager runs my presets and exports using both presets separately. The plugin used to be at this location: http://www.robcole.com/Rob/ProductsAndServices/MiscLrPlugins#ExportManager but currently the site seems to be down. Perhaps you'll be able to find the plugin elsewhere.